# Why is my code automatically changing the command "Sort" to "sORT"?

Tags: excel

When I'm writing my code the VBA automatically changes the uppercase to lowercase (from:Sort to: sORT) for all the instances, and it results in an error.

```
Sheets("Autocollect").Columns("A:M").sORT key1:=Range("D2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Something tells me you have a sub, function, or global variable that is named `sORT`

Comment: More evidence to avoid reusing reserved names.

Comment: I've search all the instances of it within the Project and replaced them all, however it changes every time. Any idea hot to look for the global variables?